# Can't compile Spring Framework code from command line

Tags: spring

I had a look to doc [Build from Source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Build-from-Source). I cloned repository, checked out master and tried to build project by executing

```
$ ./gradlew build
```

but i got error

```
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

> Task :spring-aspects:compileAspectj FAILED
[warning] couldn't find aspectjrt.jar on classpath, checked: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\classes;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-orm\build\libs\spring-orm-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-jdbc\build\libs\spring-jdbc-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-tx\build\libs\spring-tx-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-beans\build\libs\spring-beans-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-core\build\libs\spring-core-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-core\build\libs\spring-cglib-repack-3.3.0.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-core\build\libs\spring-objenesis-repack-3.1.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-jcl\build\libs\spring-jcl-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-orm\build\libs\spring-orm-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Витек\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\9205229878f3d62fbd3a32a0fb6be2d6ad8589a9\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Витек\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\25ea2e8b0c338a877313bd4672d3fe056ea78f0d\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Витек\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.aspectj\aspectjrt\1.9.4\7efb30f3259d13472ee0f92bef4319fda700f522\aspectjrt-1.9.4.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-jdbc\build\libs\spring-jdbc-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-tx\build\libs\spring-tx-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-beans\build\libs\spring-beans-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-core\build\libs\spring-core-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-core\build\libs\spring-cglib-repack-3.3.0.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-core\build\libs\spring-objenesis-repack-3.1.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-jcl\build\libs\spring-jcl-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-context-support\build\libs\spring-context-support-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-context\build\libs\spring-context-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-aop\build\libs\spring-aop-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Витек\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.cache\cache-api\1.1.0\77bdcff7814076dfa61611b0db88487c515150b6\cache-api-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Витек\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.3\e006adf5cf3cca2181d16bd640ecb80148ec0fce\javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar;E:\git\spring-framework\spring-expression\build\libs\spring-expression-5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar

[error] classpath error: unable to find org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint (check that aspectjrt.jar is in your classpath)


1 error, 1 warning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':spring-aspects:compileAspectj'.
> Compilation failed with exit code 1; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
133 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 128 up-to-date
```

But when i exclude spring-aspect tasks build is ok

```
$ ./gradlew -x :spring-aspects:compileAspectj -x :spring-aspects:compileTestAspectj build
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: http/docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5m 25s
200 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 195 up-to-date
```

Intellij IDEA configuration [doc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/import-into-idea.md) contains information

> 3. When prompted exclude the `spring-aspects` module (or after the import via File-> Project Structure -> Modules)

Should [Build from Source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Build-from-Source) doc be updated or there is other problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings GRADLE_USER_HOME env variable to path, containing only ascii chars fixes problem

```
$ GRADLE_USER_HOME=/e/.gradle ./gradlew build
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4m 25s
203 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 199 up-to-date
```